# fridgidaire range Mod. FEF358BFDC

Tags: stove

I have ordered a new rear 6 in.replacement element Ive checked many web sites to be sure I have the right number. It has only 4 electrical spades for the wires. My old one has 6 . I dont know how to make it work

Comment: Sometimes the design changes, but the new design does not fit/work with the old.  I had a similar problem a few years ago, got the same part number, but the number had an * beside it.  Contact the maker and ask.

Comment: You could post a photo of the connections and an image of the installation manual